# Jenkins docker - running a container, executing shell script etc

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I'm trying to run docker containers in the Jenkins Pipeline.

I have the following in my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('test') {
 steps {
  script {
    parallel (
        "gatling" : {
            sh 'bash ./test-gatling.sh'
    }, 
        "python" : {
            sh 'bash ./test-python.sh'
    })
               }
         }
       }
```

In the `test-gatling.sh` I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker cp RecordedSimulation.scala denvazh/gatling:/RecordedSimulation.scala
docker run -it -m denvazh/gatling /bin/bash
ls
./gatling.sh
```

The `ls` command is there just for test, but when it's executed it lists files and folders of my github repository, rather than the files inside the `denvazh/gatling` container. Why is that? I thought the `docker run -it [...]` command would open the container so that commands could be run inside it?

================

Also, how do I run a container and just have it running, without executing any commands inside it? (In the Jenkins Pipeline ofc)

I'd like to run: `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -t [my_container]` and access it on port 8080. How do I do that...?

Comment: The problem is in your bash script. Only the "/bin/bash" command is executed in your docker. The  lines below aren't automatically executed inside the bin/bash you just called.

Comment: I often have multiple `docker-compose run .....some command...` after each other in my Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone has the same or similar problem, here are the answers:

1. Use `docker exec [name of container]` command, and to run any terminal commands inside a container, add `/bin/bash -c "[command]"`
2. To be able to access a container/app that is running on any port from a second container, when starting the second container run it with `--net=host` parameter